# jquery append li's to a ul on click and then remove on second click

Tags: jquery, list, append, toggle

I would like to use an a tag to trigger appending hidden li items from a ul.

I have two uls, one that is visible as a list and another that is hidden. The hidden ul has lis that can be added to the visible list if you click a button.

I basically get the .html() for the hidden ul and then use the .append() to add them to the visible list.

This works find and dandy, but i want to treat the a link as a toggle and append/remove the hidden li's if they click it. Basically add them or remove them.

Any ideas on how to remove them on second click on the link?

Here is my jquery code:

```
// Add Related Products
$(".showProducts").click( function(){
    var moreProductsItems = $(".moreRelatedProducts").html();
    $("#myProductList").append(moreProductsItems);
    $(".showProducts").toggleClass('hideProducts');
});
```

HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="showProducts" onclick="return false;"></a>
<ul class="moreRelatedProducts" style="display:none;">
    <li>Product Name</li>
    <li>Product Name</li>
    <li>Product Name</li>
    <li>Product Name</li>
    <li>Product Name</li>
    <li>Product Name</li>
    <li>Product Name</li>
 </ul>

 <div class="listBoxContainer2">
     <ul id="myProductList">
           <li>Product Name</li>
           <li>Product Name</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), which accepts multiple handler functions for the click event.

```
$(".showProducts").toggle( function(){
    var moreProductsItems = $(".moreRelatedProducts").html();
    $("#myProductList").append(moreProductsItems);
    $(".showProducts").toggleClass('hideProducts');
}, function() {
    $("#myProductList").empty();
    $(".showProducts").toggleClass('hideProducts');
});
```

It will toggle through the functions with each click. (You could pass more than two if desired.)

---

**EDIT:** To retain the original two in the list, instead of:

```
$("#myProductList").empty();
```

...you could do:

```
$("#myProductList").children().slice(2).remove();
```

Comment: @patrick dm: This is close... i don't want to remove the two that were in the original list. Maybe i could just set a class to those originals and check if the li has a class before i remove it...

Comment: @estern: Ah yes, I didn't notice those. You would need to protect those somehow. You could perhaps divide the `#myProductsList` into two sub-containers. If there's always a maximum of two there, instead of `.empty()` you could use `$("#myProductList").children().slice(2).remove()`

Comment: I ended up doing the slice version. I do a length check to see how many li's are there that have a different class then the ones that get appended and pass this length to the .slice(). Works great.

Comment: @estern: That would definitely work. An alternative would be to do a `:not()` selection. `$("#myProductList").children(':not(.someClass)').remove()`. So many options jQuery gives us. ;o)

Comment: @patrick dm: I actually like this better. Thanks again. I would up this answer twice if I could :)

Comment: @patrick dm: I just switched the trigger to be a checkbox and something strange is happening. the check box is not selecting.. acting strange. Any thoughts... I might post a new question for this..

Comment: @estern: Hard to say. With a checkbox, you should probably use a `change` event instead of `click`. You won't be able to use the `toggle` event, but you could do `if( this.checked ) { /* add the items */ } else { /* remove the items */ });`

Answer (score 2):

Tip:

A better technique for link events.

```
<a href="#" class="showProducts" onclick="return false;"></a>
```

becomes:

```
<a href="javascript://" class="showProducts"></a>
```